# Set input for a ViewPart

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm wondering if there is any mechanism to set an input to a `ViewPart`.

For example:
My application has a search functionality. When I hit search i want to show my result in a `ViewPart` that contains a table. How can I set the input of this table, how can a transmit the results to the ViewPart? I'm currently using `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.showView(String, String, int)` to show the `ViewPart`.

I am currently using a Util class, called ViewUtil with static methods like showView(String id) and showViewWithParameter(String id, Object parameter). The second method shows the view, and save the parameter in a Map in the ViewUtil class. The createPartControl(Composite) method gets the parameter from this map and sets the input to the table. It works but I really don't like it.

Another problem is that when a call the org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.showView(String, String, int) method, if the ViewPart is already shown, the createPartControl(Composite) method is not called, thus the input of the table is not set.

I'm sure there is a better way but I can't find it.

Comment: How about adding a `Text` field to the view and entering your search there?

Comment: It could work, but the client want's to separate the search from the search results(like in Eclipse IDE). If they've done it in Eclipse IDE i'm sure there is a correct way to do this.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: Basically I want to implement a search similar to that in Eclipse IDE. I have a ViewPart that contains controls to search certain object type and their Attributes. When i hit Search, a search is performed, and the results have to be shown in a new ViewPart that contains a Table. Is it clear now? If not please tell ma the part you don't understand

Comment: Then why not add a method `setResults()` to your result view and call this with the search results?

Comment: It could work, but my ViewUtil class works with the interface IViewPart.This means that i have to introduce an abstract class in my hierarchy ,so that every ViewPart in my app, has the set results method.

Comment: If you are not pleased with this solution, feel free to look at the SWT/Eclipse source to see how they do it.

Comment: I was hoping that someone has already dealt with this problem and can same me from looking into the Eclipse IDE sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's listed as a bug in the [Eclipse BugTracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=82621).

---

I also found something that might help others. Unfortunately for me it's a no go, because you can only use String properties. Take a look at `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart3`. It has a map containing String properties and the possibility to register `propertyChangedListeners`.

---

I also found a specific solution for a search results view. Adding `org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages` extension to your plug-in xml does the trick. You then need to implement a `ISearchResultPage` which shows the results and has the `com.porsche.dps.main.SearchResultPage1.setInput(ISearchResult, Object)` method and the search result objects need to implement `ISearchResult`.